# How to give a Wordpress user (editor) permission to a special admin page?

Tags: wordpress, administration, user-roles

I want to give users with user role editor access to my plugin settings page.

.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin_settingspage

by default only admin can access this page. 
I implemented this code to protect the config page.

```
if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !current_user_can('publish_posts')) exit('Admins only.');
```

But even if I remove this line the page is still protected and for admins only. I guess this protection is done by the WP core.
So how to make the page available for users with userrole Editor?

Best Regards

Comment: Well I guess the reason is the add_menu_page command. I called it with $capability = 'manage_options';
However, is it possible regardless to current capability setup?

Comment: Well, I just answered the question myself.
add_cap("editor", "my_plugin_cap", true); brings a good result. 
I checked BaronVonKaneHoffen' s answer as accepted answer based on his good api link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be what you need to read:

[User Permissions and your Plugin](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-user-permissions-and-your-plugin/)

Not sure how you're attaching your plugins setting page at the moment, but when you do it like so:

```
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
```

You get to set the capability the user needs to see it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello BaronVonKaneHoffen,
thanks for your answer. Sorry but i added a comment to my question a few minutes ago which points directly to your suggestion.
The problem is that the settings page is not accessible via admin sidebar menu and the Editor user should not see any menu entries.

So I want to keep current capability setup.

Comment: Ha glad you got there in the end!